# Google Maps JavaScript API Pinch to Zoom Event

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is there a way to track pinch to zoom event in the JavaScript version of the Google Maps API? What I would like to do is let the user zoom by 2 levels instead of 1.

Using something like this on desktop could work:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 2);
});
```

But using the `zoom_changed` event, you can't tell whether the user is zooming out or zooming in on mobile when they are using pinch to zoom gesture.

Comment: you can keep track of zoom level with the method `getZoom()`, so you can compare it to the actual zoom and tell if user is zooming in or out.

Comment: @spezzino I don't see how. Can you provide an example? I'm just trying to think how to structure it.

Comment: see my answer below @mapr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a working example

Please insert your `APIKEY`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var zoom = 0;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
    zoom = map.getZoom();
    console.log("initial zoom: "+zoom);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
      console.log("zoom changed");
      if(map.getZoom() > zoom){
        console.log("zoomed IN");
      }else if(map.getZoom() < zoom){
        console.log("zoomed OUT");
      }
      zoom = map.getZoom();
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

After you create the map object, save its current zoom. Then in the `zoom_changed` listener, compare the stored value against the current map zoom level.

JSBin with example: http://jsbin.com/befefax/edit?html,console,output
(remember to add your own APIKEY)